# Filter array of string

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
[
  '192.168.1.1 - 192.168.2.2', 
  '192.168.2.2 - 192.168.1.1', 
  '192.168.8.8 - 192.168.9.9', 
  '192.168.9.9 - 192.168.8.8'
]
```

It is basically in this format

```
[
  'A - B', 
  'B - A',     
  'X - Y', 
  'Y - X'
]
```

so I want the resultant string in the following format, i.e want only one string from 'A - B' and 'B - A', see the required string of above arrays below

```
[
  '192.168.1.1 - 192.168.2.2', 
  '192.168.8.8 - 192.168.9.9'
]
[
  'A - B', 
  'X - Y'
]
```

Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = [
  'A - B', 
  'B - A',     
  'X - Y', 
  'Y - X'
]

const data2 = [
  '192.168.1.1 - 192.168.2.2', 
  '192.168.2.2 - 192.168.1.1', 
  '192.168.8.8 - 192.168.9.9', 
  '192.168.9.9 - 192.168.8.8'
]


const result = data => [...new Set(data.map(d => JSON.stringify(d.split(' - ').sort())))].map(s => JSON.parse(s).join(' - '))

console.log(result(data))


console.log(result(data2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
            '192.168.1.1 - 192.168.2.2',
            '192.168.2.2 - 192.168.1.1',
            '192.168.8.8 - 192.168.9.9',
            '192.168.9.9 - 192.168.8.8'
        ]

        var a = arr.filter( x => arr.indexOf(x) % 2 == 0);
        console.log(a);
```